# ipython use "%run" to execute a subset of a file

Tags: python, ipython, magic-function

Is there some way I can use %run to execute a subset of a file?

Something like this:

```
$ ipython
In [1]: %run my_code.py -L 20 100 # executes lines 20-100 in ipython interpereter
```

Comment: I can hardly imagine this being an often used feature. Could you explain why you'd want to do that and not, for example, wrap lines 20-100 in a function and just `import my_code; my_function_spanning_20_to_100()`?

Comment: Agreed, Most of the time it's because people want to mutate locals and globals when using %run. but your function can just take theses as arguments.

Comment: You can `%load -r 20-100 my_code.py`, which will put that content in the next input cell, so you can run it.

Comment: @ThomasK, isn't that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%run` doesn't have an option for this. You can see all the options it takes by doing `%run?` inside IPython.

However, you can bring a specific range of lines from a file into the interactive prompt, and run it from there. The syntax to do this looks like:

```
%load -r 20-100 my_code.py
```